# Pre-check x-editable radiolist when initial value is zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, x-editable

I am using an radiolist with x-editable.  If the initial value is not zero (`1` for example), the x-editable dialog pre-checks the radio button, but this is not the case if the initial value is zero.  Probably best to just check out https://jsfiddle.net/1330379z/1/.  Anyone know how to do this?

```
<p>Start with Yes</p><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="radio" data-value="1"></a>

<br>
<p>Start with No</p><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="radio" data-value="0"></a>

<br>One
<input type="radio" name="test" value="1">
<br>
Zero<input type="radio" name="test" value="0">

$('.radio').editable({
    type: 'radiolist',
    title: "Select yes or no",
    source: [{
        value: 0,
        text: 'No'
    }, {
        value: 1,
        text: 'Yes'
    }]
});
```

Comment: I acknowledge there is probably not much experience with this.  I will likely change my primary value to "y" and "n" instead of 1 and 0 which should eliminate the issue.